DeepDiff "values_changed" is not making sense when comparing list of dicts
Trying to use DeepDiff to compare two lists of dicts and the resulting diff isn't making sense to me.  Code is:
new_config = [
    {'peer-address': '10.1.1.0', 'description': 'switch1a.rk01', 'peer-group': 'V4'},
    {'peer-address': '10.1.1.4', 'description': 'switch1b.rk01', 'peer-group': 'V4'},
    {'peer-address': 'fc03::', 'description': 'switch1a.rk01', 'peer-group': 'V6'},
    {'peer-address': 'fc03::4', 'description': 'switch1b.rk01', 'peer-group': 'V6'}
]
old_config = [
    {'peer-address': '1.1.1.1', 'description': 'foo', 'peer-group': 'TEST'}
]
diff = DeepDiff(new_config, old_config, ignore_order=True)

print(json.dumps(diff, indent=2))

{
    "iterable_item_added": {
        "root[1]": {
            "description": "switch1b.rk01",
            "peer-address": "10.1.1.4",
            "peer-group": "V4"
        },
        "root[2]": {
            "description": "switch1a.rk01",
            "peer-address": "fc03::",
            "peer-group": "V6"
        },
        "root[3]": {
            "description": "switch1b.rk01",
            "peer-address": "fc03::4",
            "peer-group": "V6"
        }
    },
    "values_changed": {
        "root[0]": {
            "new_value": {
                "description": "switch1a.rk01",
                "peer-address": "10.1.1.0",
                "peer-group": "V4"
            },
            "old_value": {
                "description": "foo",
                "peer-address": "1.1.1.1",
                "peer-group": "TEST"
            }
        }
    }
}

I don't understand why i'm seeing anything in the values_changed section.  I was expecting to just see four entries under iterable_item_added

The dict in old_config is not in new_config, so the dict must either be deleted or modified (what DeepDiff does).
